# UITableview clipsToBounds

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5

I am creating an iPad view which has a tableview as a subview. The tableview only takes a small portion of the screen and is somewhere near the middle of the screen and it contains some menu items. I want people to be about to scroll this tableview up and down however I do not like how the cells disappear against a hard edge. When I set clipsToBounds to false, I get what I want in that the hard edge is not there anymore but the top/bottom cell disappears when the tableview needs that cell for recycling. Is there a common technique to avoid this hard-edge of when the cells scroll up against the tableview's bounds? I was thinking of adding gradient alpha masks on a parent container view but it seems a bit over the top.

Answer (score 0):

There are no hard and fast rule about this, but you certainly can do whatever you feel best. What I would do in a case of floating tableView is giving it a nice border using layer. It is easy to code (2~3 lines). Round the edge to make it pretty.

If you want to drop shadow, it gets a little more complicated but possible. Just draw a bezier curve path of a rectangle (where you want your shadow to appear). Assign that CALayer shadowPath. Then add it to the table.

You can also gradient an alpha to make it appear shadow like.

But I would suggest, you set `clipsToBounds` to `YES` since it looks horrible otherwise, given the fact that the table 'floats' somewhere in your view.